# No memory window in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I have VS2010 Premium RTM version on Windows 7 Ultimate **x64**.

In the documentation they refer to the Memory 1-4 windows, supposedly under Debug->Windows->Memory.

I have "Enable address-level debugging" enabled in VS (Options->Debugging).

The problem is that I have no Memory menu item under Debug->Windows during debug of a c++ program.

Under Debug->Windows I have only:
Breakpoints
Parallel Tasks
Parallel Stacks
Watch ->
Locals
Call Stack
Threads

Have anyone else experienced this (and hopefully solved it)?

Comment: Also running Visual Studio 2010 Premium RTM on Win7 (Pro) x64, and the windows are there. Just to confirm that the memory windows are supposed to be there in this configuration.

Comment: They're even there when running managed (C#) code, not that you need them then.

Comment: When I'm debugging assembly language programs, the memory window only shows up for me (in Visual C++ 2010 Express) when I use "Step into.", with "Expert Settings" enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During the first run of VS after installation it asks you which "mode" it should run in, depending on your selection it shows or hides various menu items etc. Maybe you selected an option that hid those windows? This is described at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx) page.

I think you can use the information on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1z20s6z.aspx) page to change those settings.

You might also be able to just run `Devenv /ResetSettings` to reset them, but not sure exactly what you'd end up with then...

Comment: That solved it for me, imported the Visual C++ settings.

Thank you, you have saved my day!

Comment: Also, which settings would I need to select in order to enable the memory window options?

Comment: Also, where should I run `Devenv /ResetSettings`?

Comment: @AndersonGreen DevEnv is the executable, so just open a visual studio command prompt. Not 100% sure which setting you should use, but since C++ is the one that sounds most likely to use the Memory window I'd guess at that.

Comment: @FredrikJansson How did you import the Visual C++ settings? I'm still trying to figure out how to do this. :/

Comment: Also, is it possible to show all of the menu items at the same time in Visual Studio (instead of just showing some of them)?

Comment: That didn't work for me. Don't see Debug | Windows | [Memory | Disassembly | Registers] option. Added them manually but they appear disabled :(

Answer (score 4):

Go to command Window and type in memory. It will show the Memory 1 watch window. I had to do that because I still can't find the debug command for it under customize even.

Answer (score 4):

You can switch to expert mode by checking :

```
Tools > Settings > Expert Settings
```

Now you can show up Registers Window and much more other windows

Answer (score 2):

The Memory window is available only if address-level debugging is enabled in the Options dialog box, Debugging node. The Memory window is not available for Script or SQL, which are languages that do not recognize the concept of memory.

or go here for other details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx